# Cannot find JsonWriter or JsonFormat type class

Tags: scala, spray, spray-json

The below code is unable to find JsonWriter or JsonFormat type class:

```
import com.typesafe.scalalogging.LazyLogging
import spray.json._

case class MatcherRequest2(dataType:String, testType:String)

object MatcherWriterJsonSupport2 extends /*SprayJsonSupport with*/ DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val matcherRequest = jsonFormat2(MatcherRequest2)
}

object MatcherTransfer2 extends LazyLogging {
  import MatcherWriterJsonSupport2.rmobMatcherRequest
  def fetchSignExtractionDone: Unit = {

    val matcherRequest: MatcherRequest2 = MatcherRequest2("FeatureCollection", "testC")
    matcherRequest.toJson
  }
}
```

Error:

> Error:(24, 24) Cannot find JsonWriter or JsonFormat type class for
>   MatcherRequest2
>       rmobMatcherRequest.toJson
>
> Error:(24, 24) not enough arguments for method toJson: (implicit
>   writer: spray.json.JsonWriter[MatcherRequest2])spray.json.JsValue.
>   Unspecified value parameter writer.
>       rmobMatcherRequest.toJson

Answer (score 3):

Ugh, my bad. The variable name matcherRequest is same for implicit variable and in the MatcherTransfer2 object which was causing the above error.

> implicit val matcherRequest = jsonFormat2(MatcherRequest2)

replace by

> implicit val matcherRequestFormat = jsonFormat2(MatcherRequest2)